# Model performance calculation when class labels are not as expected

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

Hi I'm training a neural network. The training dataset has its labels as benign or malignant. So I coveted it into numerical values using,

```
class_data= pd.factorize(class_data)[0]
```

So now the malignant has been given-0 (which is cancerous)
and benign - 1 (non-cancerous)

Now the confusion matrix looked like below

[image]
I need to calculate sensitivity, specificity. And it was calculated as below

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(test_y,y_pred).ravel()

# Accuracy : 
acc_ = (tp + tn) / (tp + tn + fn + fp)
print("Accuracy  : ", acc_)
# Sensitivity : 
sens_ = tp / (tp + fn)
print("Sensitivity  : ", sens_)
# Specificity 
sp_ = tn / (tn + fp)
print("Specificity  : ", sp_)
# False positive rate (FPR)
FPR = fp / (tn + fp)
print("False positive rate  : ", FPR)
```

Since my class labels are incorrectly labeled, can someone let me know the calculations are getting miss interpreted? 
PS:

```
...tn... 29
...fp... 15
...fn... 14
...tp... 85
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure your calculation is correct you can find F1 score manually as

```
F1Score= 2tp/(2tp+fp+fn)
```

Then compare your value with

```
sklearn.metrics.f1_score(test_y, y_pred)
```

You can also use the labels parameter to make sure the labels are correct.

```
confusion_matrix(test_y,y_pred,labels=[0,1]).ravel()
```

Comment: Thanks... I think this is wrong .... :( ..Please see my updated answer. Do you know how the labels can be forced to interpret like correctly. currently its with malignant and benign. I need malignant to be 1 and benign to be 0.

Comment: you can change labels as labels[1,0]. Now you can interpret the matrix as if 1 is malignant and 0 benign.

Answer (score 1):

To be safe, you could just calculate each cell explicitly instead 
of using `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix()`, and then proceed from there:

```
# some fake data (assumes labels are boolean)
test_y = [True, True, False, False, True]
y_pred = [True, False, True, False, True]

idx_range = range(len(test_y))

tn = sum([not test_y[idx] and not y_pred[idx] for idx in idx_range])
fp = sum([not test_y[idx] and y_pred[idx] for idx in idx_range])
fn = sum([test_y[idx] and not y_pred[idx] for idx in idx_range])
tp = sum([test_y[idx] and y_pred[idx] for idx in idx_range])

# ... and then calculate the metrics
```

If you prefer using `pandas.factorize()`, you can also force it to map `True` to `1` and `False` to `0` by setting `sort=True`:

```
test_y = [True, True, False, False, True]
y_pred = [True, False, True, False, True]

# pd.factorize() returns a tuple so get the data (0th elem)
test_y_factor = pd.factorize(test_y, sort=True)[0]
y_pred_factor = pd.factorize(y_pred, sort=True)[0]

# confirm that the translation happened properly:
[*zip(test_y, test_y_factor[0])]
## 
## output: 
## [(True, 1), (True, 1), (False, 0), (False, 0), (True, 1)]
```